# Need help in designing my DB in Cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp

This should be real easy for all you Cakephp guys out there.
I want to properly design my DB for a Cakephp project.
Its pretty simple.  I will have a Users table and a Activities table.
A User can and will have many Activities.  And an Activity can and will have many Users.
An example....User#1 has Tennis, Golf and Basketball for activities.  And the Activity "Golf" has User#1, #6, #10, and #15.

So the Activities table will be static.  Just a simple list of Activity_ID and things like Golf, Tennis, etc.
And each user will relate to each item in the Activities table with a field called Activities. So the Activity row would look something like this.....3,5,15,21,30

So my question is....how do I design this using Cake Bake?  What do I specify when I Bake the Models?

Do I use hasOne or hasAndBelongsToMany or what?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a hasAndBelongsToMany.  From the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html):

> hasAndBelongsToMany - Recipes have, and belong to, many ingredients.

So, in your case the users are the recipes and the activities are the ingredients.